# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cloud') Elastic Search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, nestjs

I'm trying to use `ElasticSearch` in a `NestJs` project.

The problem is after setting up everything I'm getting this error:

```
 ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cloud')
```

[image]

search.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
  constructor(private readonly elasticsearchService: ElasticsearchService) {}
}
```

search.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    ElasticsearchModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) =>
        ConfigSearch.searchConfig(config.get('ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL')),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [ElasticsearchModule, SearchService],
  exports: [ElasticsearchModule],
})
export class SearchModule {}
```

search.config.ts

```
export class ConfigSearch {
  public static searchConfig(url: string): any {
    return {
      node: url,
      maxRetries: 5,
      requestTimeout: 60000,
      sniffOnStart: true,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: show us how your setup of `@nestjs/elasticsearch` looks like

Comment: @MicaelLevi Added the files.

Comment: why do you have `ElasticsearchModule` listed in your providers array? `providers` are for providers, not for modules